# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am creating a ReactJS form using React Hook Form. After defining the form fields, validation rules using register function and validation schema using yup object, I am still getting this error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import "./Userform.css";

function Userform() {
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required("Name is required"),
    dobOrAge: yup.string().required("Age is required"),
    sex: yup.string().required("Sex is required"),
    mobile: yup
      .string()
      .matches(
        /^[6-9]\d{9}$/,
        "Mobile number must be a valid Indian mobile number"
      )
      .nullable(),
    idType: yup.string().nullable(),
    id: yup.string().when("idType", {
      is: "Aadhar",
      then: yup
        .string()
         .matches(/^\d{12}$/, "Govt Id must be a valid 12-digit numeric string")
        .nullable(),
       otherwise: yup
        .string()
        .matches(
           /^[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}$/,
          "Govt Id must be a valid 10-digit alpha-numeric string"
        )
        .nullable(),
    }),
    email: yup.string("Email must be a valid email address").nullable(),
    emergencyContactNumber: yup
      .string()
      .matches(
        /^[6-9]\d{9}$/,
        "Emergency Contact Number must be a valid Indian mobile number"
      )
      .nullable(),
    guardianTitle: yup.string().nullable(),
    guardianName: yup.string().nullable(),
     address: yup.string().nullable(),
     country: yup.string().nullable(),
     state: yup.string().nullable(),
     pincode: yup.string().nullable(),
     city: yup.string().nullable(),
     occupation: yup.string().nullable(),
     nationality: yup.string().nullable(),
     religion: yup.string().nullable(),
     maritalStatus: yup.string().nullable(),
     bloodGroup: yup.string().nullable(),
   });

   const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
   } = useForm({
      resolver: yupResolver(schema),
   });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
     console.log(data);
   };

   return (
     <div className="form-container">
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <div>
      <h2 className="form-heading">Personal Details</h2>
      <label className="form-label"> Name: </label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your full name"
        {...register("name", { required: true })}
      />
      {errors.name && <p className="form-error">{errors.name.message}</p>}
      <label className="form-label">Date of Birth / Age :</label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("dobOrAge", { required: true })}
      />
      {errors.dobOrAge && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.dobOrAge.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Sex :</label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("sex", { required: true })}
      />
      {errors.sex && <p className="form-error">{errors.sex.message}</p>}
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Mobile:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("mobile")} />
      {errors.mobile && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.mobile.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <label className="form-label">ID Type:</label>
      <select className="form-select" {...register("idType")}>
        <option value="">Select ID Type</option>
        <option value="Aadhar">Aadhar</option>
        <option value="PAN">PAN</option>
      </select>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("id")} />
      {errors.id && <p className="form-error">{errors.id.message}</p>}
    </div>

    <h2 className="form-heading">Contact Details</h2>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Email:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="email" {...register("email")} />
      {errors.email && <p className="form-error">{errors.email.message}</p>}
      <label className="form-label">Emergency contact number:</label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("emergencyContactNumber")}
      />
      {errors.emergencyContactNumber && (
        <p className="form-error">
          {errors.emergencyContactNumber.message}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Guardian Details:</label>
      <select className="form-select" {...register("guardianTitle")}>
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
      </select>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("guardianName")}
      />
      {errors.guardianName && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.guardianName.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>

    <h2 className="form-heading">Address Details</h2>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Address:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("address")} />
      {errors.address && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.address.message}</p>
      )}

      <label className="form-label">Country:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("country")} />
      {errors.country && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.country.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>

    <div>
      <label className="form-label">State:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("state")} />
      {errors.state && <p className="form-error">{errors.state.message}</p>}
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Pincode:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("pincode")} />
      {errors.pincode && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.pincode.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">City:</label>
      <input className="form-input" type="text" {...register("city")} />
      {errors.city && <p className="form-error">{errors.city.message}</p>}
    </div>

    <h2 className="form-heading">Other Details</h2>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Occupation</label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("occupation")}
      />
      {errors.occupation && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.occupation.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Religion</label>
      <select className="form-select" {...register("religion")}>
        <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
        <option value="Muslim">Muslim</option>
        <option value="Christian">Christian</option>
        <option value="Sikh">Sikh</option>
        <option value="Jain">Jain</option>
        <option value="Buddhist">Buddhist</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Marital status</label>
      <select className="form-select" {...register("marital")}>
        <option value="Married">Married</option>
        <option value="Unmarried">Unmarried</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Blood Group</label>
      <select className="form-select" {...register("blood")}>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="O">O</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label className="form-label">Nationality</label>
      <input
        className="form-input"
        type="text"
        {...register("nationality")}
      />
      {errors.nationality && (
        <p className="form-error">{errors.nationality.message}</p>
      )}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
  );
}

export default Userform;
```

what should be done to remove the above error?

Comment: which line throws this error? I don't see any variable `set`

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't see any set as well. Still this error is being given.